# combining tqdm with delayed execution with dask in python

Tags: python, dask, tqdm

`tqdm` and `dask` are both amazing packages for iterations in python. While `tqdm` implements the needed progress bar, `dask` implements the multi-thread platform and they both can make iteration process less frustrating. Yet - I'm having troubles to combine them both together.

For example, the following code implements a delayed execution in `dask`, with `tqdm.trange` progress bar. The thing is that since the `delayed` is performed quickly, the progress bar ends immediately, while the real computation-time effort is done during the `compute` part.

```
from dask import delayed,compute
from tqdm import trange
from time import sleep

ct = time()
result= []

def fun(x):
    sleep(x)
    return x

for i in trange(10):
    result.append(delayed(fun)(i))

print compute(result)
```

How can I attach the progress bar to the actual execution in `compute` command?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Consider Dask's progress bar

```
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

with ProgressBar():
    compute(result)
```

#### Build a diagnostic of your own

You can use this plugin architecture to get a signal at the end of every task.  http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html

Here is an example of someone doing exactly this: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/278

Comment: Nice! Is there any solution close to ``tqdm_notebook`` progress bar?

Comment: I don't know of anything.  You could probably extend the tqdm PR listed above.

Comment: Oh, if you're asking about Dask solutions the dask.distributed progress bars are decent.  There is also the diagnostic dashboard.  See example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ods97a5Pzw0&list=PLRtz5iA93T4PQvWuoMnIyEIz1fXiJ5Pri

Answer (score 5):

Based on :

[Dask Integration](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#dask-integration)

```py
from tqdm.dask import TqdmCallback

with TqdmCallback(desc="compute"):
    ...
    arr.compute()

# or use callback globally
cb = TqdmCallback(desc="global")
cb.register()
arr.compute()
```

Applied to the code in the question:

```py
from dask import delayed,compute
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
# from tqdm import trange
from time import sleep

from tqdm.dask import TqdmCallback

# ct = time()
result= []

def fun(x):
    sleep(x)
    return x

for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    result.append(delayed(fun)(i))

with TqdmCallback(desc="compute"):
    print(compute(result))
```

screenshot of output in jupyter :
[image]

Comment: Interesting and useful, thanks!