# How to see progress of Dask compute task?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, distributed-computing, dask

I would like to see a progress bar on Jupyter notebook while I'm running a compute task using Dask, I'm counting all values of `id` column from a large csv file +4GB, so any ideas?

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('data/train.csv')
df.id.count().compute()
```

Comment: Have you checked: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483950/combining-tqdm-with-delayed-execution-with-dask-in-python

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you're using the single machine scheduler then do this:

```
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
ProgressBar().register()
```

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html

If you're using the distributed scheduler then do this:

```
from dask.distributed import progress

result = df.id.count.persist()
progress(result)
```

Or just use the dashboard

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html

Comment: Is there any chance to see total time to complete a task on the Dashboard?

Comment: An individual function/task?  No.  Tasks contain arbirary Python code and so behave in unpredictable ways.

Comment: when running the .register where would one see the progress bar?

Comment: When I use dask with the progress bar, it just freezes on zero while generating enough heat and CPU usage that I presume it's doing something. How does the progress bar get updated?

Comment: This is great for running Dask on Kaggle, which does not seem to support the dashboard (see https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/54405)

Comment: Thank you, this is so very helpful!

Comment: If tqdm is preferred, in the `distributed` case, you can also `import tqdm` and `from dask.distributed import as_completed`, then do `futures = client.submit(func, iter)` and `for _ in tqdm(as_completed(futures), total=len(iter)): pass`

Answer (score 0):

[This resource](https://coiled.io/blog/how-to-check-the-progress-of-dask-computations/) provides full-code examples for both cases (local and distributed) and more detailed information about using the Dask Dashboard.

Note that when working in Jupyter notebooks you may have to separate the `ProgressBar().register()` call and the computation call you want to track (e.g. `df.set_index('id').persist()`) into two separate cells for the progress bar to actually appear.

DO:

[image]

DON'T DO:

[image]

Comment: Link is dead....