# Using tqdm with dask distributed

Tags: python, dask, tqdm

I use the following code to parallelize my image processing function:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask.distributed import progress

def processImage(image_in_path, image_out_path)
    im = read_image(image_path)
    im_processed = gradient(im)
    write_image(im, image_out_path)

client = Client()

in_list = list_image(dir_path)
out_list = ...
comp = client.map(processImage, in_list, out_list)
progress(comp)
```

As I'm using tqdm in my code already, and I like its features, is it possible to use it to draw the progress of such computation?

I've see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44484119/5547936) linking to a [tqdm pull request](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/pull/279), but I think it is for the dask local, not the dask distributed. So it is not made for the distributed interface. Or maybe I'm missing something...

I went a bit in the code of dask progress, but it is unclear to me how I could plug tqdm to it...

Any solution ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, you could implement a tqdm progress bar in the same way that dask's `progress` function is implemented.  You would probably want to use the `feed` route to get a feed of updates as work completes.